# Swift: UIImageView - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, uiimageview

```
class DisplayImageVC: BasePageView { //BasePageView inherits from UIViewController

    @IBOutlet weak var displayImage: UIImageView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.displayImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }
```

....

in another class I try this and get a fatal error:

```
    var displayImageView = self._pageContent[1] as DisplayImageVC        
    displayImageView.displayImage.image = UIImage(named: ("displayChecklane"))
```

**Log:**

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image]

Images.xcassets
[image]

Comment: Why the extra parentheses? just say `named: "displayChecklane"`

Comment: Why are you not supplying a `3x` image? You will need one on iPhone 6 Plus.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var displayImageView = self._pageContent[1] as DisplayImageVC        
displayImageView.displayImage.image = UIImage(named: ("displayChecklane"))
```

You are crashing on the second line. You know this is because something is nil, but you do not know what is nil here. You are assuming it is the image. That is a false assumption; if it were correct, there would be no crash, as you are not force-unwrapping it, and it is legal to assign nil to an image view's image.

Instead, consider this: maybe `displayImageView.displayImage` is nil. That is, what is nil is the UIImageView you are trying to assign *to*. This would make sense since this is an outlet. If the DisplayImageVC's view has not loaded, its outlets have not been filled - they are still nil.

How you solve this depends on what you want to do. Personally I think your approach is bogus from the start; you have no business setting another view controller's outlet or a property of its outlet, or any aspect of its interface. You should have an `image` property in DisplayImageVC, and here, you should be setting that property; that way, when the view controller shows its view, *it* can configure its own interface.

Comment: This is a gold answer !!